# Is there any button/badge we can use for Google Wallet Digital Goods?

Tags: android-pay

For Google Wallet Digital Goods,

a) is there any icon/graphic thing we can use on the main page/landing page to advertise that we're using Google Wallet?

b) does Google provide a checkout/buy button?

Comment: This question is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find Wallet UI branding guidelines (including logos, acceptance badges, etc.) in the Wallet developers documentation site:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/ui-branding#acceptance_graphics_usage

Comment: These look great. Still unsure if I can use any of them for Google Wallet **Digital Goods**. (You're linking to their **Instant Buy** API.)

Comment: The logos and badges can be used for any transaction that is using Google Wallet as the payment method, i.e. it is ok to use them for the Wallet for digital goods API.

Answer (score 1):

UI branding assets for "Google Wallet for digital goods" can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/ui-branding).

[image: Buy with Google button]

[image: Acceptance badge]

Answer (score 0):

a) There currently isn't an official acceptance logo, but you could copy just the image from: https://checkout.google.com/seller/acceptance_logos.html and use that.

b) We don't force a buy button, you can use any that you want.

Comment: `Usage Requirements: Use only the Google-hosted version by copy/pasting the code snippet from the Google Checkout Merchant Center.` But there is no such thing, or I don't find it.

Answer (score -1):

This image should get the point across:

[image]https://checkout.google.com/seller/images/acceptancelogo/logo-0-f-en_us.png

Comment: And this thing should link to exactly ... what?